# Gitlab deploy keys configured but still doesn't grant access

Tags: git, ssh, deployment, gitlab

I just configured Gitlab with a deploy key so that it doesn't ask for a username and password every time—but when pulling, it still fails with the following error:

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey, keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What I did so far is this:

1. Generated the SSH key that can be found under `~/.ssh/`
2. Copied and pasted `id_rsa.pub` in the Gitlab deploy keys section
3. Added the key to the SSH registery with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
4. Setup a config file under `~/.ssh` with following contents:

   ```
   Host gitlab.co
   RSAAuthentication yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```
5. Changed the `git remote` from the one using HTTPs to the one using SSH.

I searched both Google and StackOverflow for a possible solution, but didn't find any similar discussion. Any ideas what I may be missing?

Answer (score 2):

I was using `sudo` to do `git pull`, which resulted in the server trying to authenticate with the sudo user's SSH key.

I fixed it by changing the owner of the `.git` directory to be my logged-in user, meaning this command:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu .git
```

After this, it all worked fine.

I believe this is a common scenario and I am now surprised I couldn't find more info about this.

Answer (score 0):

I have another situation, it runs well before, but in a few days I have not use the **git pull**,
and today, it returns

```
root@api-test:~# git clone git@gitlab.com:xxxx.git
Cloning into 'designcfg'...
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

when I tried.

And I change the **.ssh/config** from

```
Host gitlab
    Hostname gitlab.com
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/xxx_rsa
```

to

```
Host gitlab.com
    Hostname gitlab.com
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/xxx_rsa
```

It works again.